# How to disable kdeconnectd autostart?

Tags: kde, kde-connect

I've tried both copying `/etc/xdg/autostart/kdeconnectd.desktop` to `~/.config/autostart` and editing it and editing it directly but it didn't help.

Update: Looks like it's from `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.kdeconnect.service` and I don't see any way to disable DBus services.

Comment: Standard way to disable services is `sudo systectl disable kdeconnectd`. You might want to stop it first and might need to `mask` it (see `man systemctl`) and can check on the `status`.

Comment: But there is no `kdeconnectd.service`, is there? (also there is a typo in `systectl`, for anyone who wants to try)

Comment: Yes, it should be `systemctl`; yes, you're right systemd does start kdeconnect (on my Kubuntu 22.04) but it doesn't run as a service as you note.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to disable it on autostart, but I asked around on the kde forums and got:

```
qdbus org.kde.kde /modules/kdeconnect [start|stop]
```

You can use tab completion with `qdbus`

I think it's only per-session.

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=140535

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't see any stop method on any related DBus service with `qdbusviewer`. What version are you using? I'm on 1.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to disable this service is to rename its desktop launcher:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop.bak
```

After reboot it won't start automatically anymore. If you wish to revert this behavior, just rename its launcher back.
As long as you avoid visiting **KDE Connect** in **System Settings** it will not start again. If you wish, you can turn off executable bit of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd` to prevent its spawning completely (found this proposal [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384306)).

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't need to use KDE Connect even occasionally: you can just uninstall it. At least on my Kubuntu 22.04 setup, `kdeconnect` is an optional package

Comment: Whilst this does disable, the questioner probably wanted the option to run manually. The answer would be better (for novices) if you mentioned how to remove. Welcome to AU.

Comment: That's not what I needed but it's also great news, thanks! Please leave this answer in place, mods.